# How to replace JMenuItem with JMenu (without re-ordering)

Tags: java, swing, menu

I have a menu that starts out as a JMenuItem. When it's selected I want it its action listener to replace that menu item with a menu with sub-menu items.

I tried using `parentMenu.remove(subMenuItem); parentMenu.add(subMenu);` but this moves the menu to the bottom of its parents menu items. I want it to stay where it is in the parents menu items.

Do I have to re-create the parent menu?

(I can write/provide a SSCCE if you really think that it's necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
Container.add(component, index);
```

method to insert the menu wherever you want.

Of course you would need to find the appropriate index by using another `Container` method to iterate through all the components in the container.

Comment: Thanks! I'd just found the add(menu, index) and was wondering how to get the index… searching stack overflow I found .getComponentZOrder but that's returning -1 (not found?). I ended up iterating over the parent menu components and replacing it when found… I'll write up an answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I found (and camickr suggested) I use `.add(subMenu, index)`; that lead to asking "How do I find my index in my parent menu?". Searching stack overflow for that I found `.getComponentZOrder()` but that's always returning -1 (not found?). So I ended up going with this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < parentMenu.getMenuComponentCount(); i++) {
        if (parentMenu.getMenuComponent(i) == subMenuItem) {
            checkMenu.remove(subMenuItem);
            checkMenu.add(subMenu, i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Edit: I've figured out the `.getComponentZOrder()` way also:

```
Container container = subMenuItem.getParent();
if (container != null) {
    int index = container.getComponentZOrder(subMenuItem);
    if (index > -1) {
        checkMenu.remove(subMenuItem);
        checkMenu.add(subMenu, index);
    }
}
```

(It is one more line of code and I suspect `.getComponentZOrder` is pretty much doing the same work so I'll probably just go with iterating the sub-menu(Item)s myself.)